# Read CSV except first row through CSVReader

Tags: csv

I wanted to know if there is any way I can read a CSV file except the first row (the header) and the first column of each row? I figured that if I skip the 0th element of the array nextLine[], I can skip the first column of each row, but could anyone please help me how to skip the first row that contains the headings, I need to retrieve only the data, not the headings. Below is my code:

```
if (CSValreadyExists)
    {
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String [] nextLine;
        try {
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                //System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");

                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[0]); // Factor
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[1]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[2]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[4]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[5]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[6]); // Scale

                Toast.makeText(this, nextLine[1] + "-" + nextLine[2]
                         + "-" + nextLine[3] + "-" + nextLine[4] + "-" + nextLine[5]
                                 + "-" + nextLine[6], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
if (CSValreadyExists)
    {
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String [] nextLine;
        try {
            boolean headersConsumed = false; // helper flag
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                //System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");

                if(!headersConsumed){ // if headers not consumed
                    headersConsumed = true;
                    continue; // skip line with headers
                } 

                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[0]); // Factor
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[1]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[2]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[4]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[5]); // Scale
                scalesFromCSV.add(nextLine[6]); // Scale

                Toast.makeText(this, nextLine[1] + "-" + nextLine[2]
                         + "-" + nextLine[3] + "-" + nextLine[4] + "-" + nextLine[5]
                                 + "-" + nextLine[6], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a custom logic for skipping header, you can make use of the corresponding constructor. The last argument is skipLines and default is zero(`CSVReader.DEFAULT_SKIP_LINES`) so it reads header.

```
new CSVReader(new FileReader(pathToData), CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 1);
```